# ie text display cleartype in some places but not others

Tags: internet-explorer, text, internet-explorer-8, fonts, smoothing

I have a strange problem. The text in my footer is displaying as smooth, but  none of the rest of the text on the website is in ie8.

I read somewhere that using position:absolute would help. I put this in the body tag, but that stopped my gallery and contact form from working correctly.

So after much searching for an answer I am stuck.

Not sure what to do. All other sites I view are displayed as cleartype, so it's not my ie settings. It must be something I've done to my site.

http://universalcrm.co.uk/casamancini/

If my text isn't in a div tag it is smooth. 
My divs are positioned float:left.

Comment: Animations and opacity tend to remove cleartype

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Added `position: relative` to the `p` and `h2` tags rather than the whole `body`.